# How to access the folder name before the pb file is saved by Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have saved a pb file with a Tensorflow script but it seems that the output folder, which I specified, is used as a parent folder and Tensorflow created a subfolder with a numeric title (e.g. 1586312775) then saved the pb file within it.

```
estimator.export_savedmodel('/model_output', serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn())
```

And the output folder structure looks like this:

```
model_output -- 1586312775 -- variables
                           -- saved_model.pb
```

Is there any method to access the automatic folder name (1586312775) which is created by Tensorflow?
Can I change the name of the folder before it saves the pb file under it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_dist_folder_name(estimator):
    job_name = estimator.latest_training_job.job_name
    base_job_name = estimator.base_job_name
    job_timestamp = job_name[job_name.find(base_job_name)+len(base_job_name)+1:][:-4]
    target_folder_name = str(int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(job_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").timetuple())))
    return target_folder_name
```

BTW, I was doing this this on AWS and this will get the timestamp folder name....